# How to create a CNAME record using POWERSHELL when TLD hosted on O365?

Tags: powershell, azure, dns, office365, azure-devops

**PROBLEM**

TLD hosted on Office 365 and makes use of the Office 365 NAME SERVER. As part of a VSTS Release Pipeline deployment to an Azure App Service I have a requirement to create a CNAME record using a Powershell script at execution time. The deployment is idempotent.

**TESTED**

- Run Powershell as local admin user.
- Download powershell AD tools MSI:
  http://connect.microsoft.com/site1164/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=59185
- Connect to the directory using and the Office365 admin auth credentials:

  ```
  Connect-MsolService
  ```
- Execute

  ```
  New-MsolDomain -name test.com
  ```

At this stage domain TEST.COM appears as an unverified domain in my Office365 DOMAIN setup section.

Great, so I have:

- Proven I can connect to the correct endpoint.
- Authenticate into the correct account.
- Have permission to create a record, albeit an unverified TLD at this stage.

**QUESTION**

Looking at the available Powershell commands I do not understand how to create an CNAME on an existing verified TLD hosted on the same account.

**RESEARCH**

Have looked at the documentation for:

[New-MSOL commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/new-msoldomain?view=azureadps-1.0)

[New-AzureRmDnsZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.dns/new-azurermdnszone?view=azurermps-4.3.1)

RM being Azure Resource Manager , its not clear if the O365 NameSever is Azure DNS.

Also had a look at this, but I dont think its possible to use these commands with O365:

[Add-DnsServerResourceRecordCName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/add-dnsserverresourcerecordcname?view=win10-ps)

Edited to add I also examined [Azure Active Directory PowerShell Version 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0):

```
Install-Module AzureAD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May almost be there. The following process seems to be allowing me to create the appropriate records. Will edit the below with progress.

1. Install Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant for IT Professionals RTW:

   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41950
2. Install Azure Active Directory Connection MSI@

   http://connect.microsoft.com/site1164/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=59185
3. From Powershell as ADMIN install Connection Assistant:

   ```
   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/0/1/5017D39B-8E29-48C8-91A8-8D0E4968E6D4/en/msoidcli_64.msi -OutFile c:\msoidcli_64.msi
   ```

   Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList /i, c:\msoidcli_64.msi, /quiet -Wait
4. Install the Admin Config:

   ```
   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=236297 -OutFile c:\AdministrationConfig-en.msi
   ```

   Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList /i, c:\AdministrationConfig-en.msi, /quiet -Wait
5. Install NuGet package:

   ```
   Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
   ```
6. Install ARM DNS module:

   ```
   Install-Module AzureRM.Dns -Confirm:$false -Force
   ```
7. Connect to O365 then enter your O365 AD user credentials.

   ```
   Connect-MsolService
   ```
8. Connect to Azure sub and enter your Azure subscription user credentials.

   ```
   Login-AzureRmAccount
   ```
9. Select the related Azure Sub related to your O365 sub:

   ```
   Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscriptionname O365
   ```
10. Execute the following to add a CNAME record:

    ```
    New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -Name 'test1' -RecordType "CName" -ZoneName mydomain.com -ResourceGroupName "Name" -Ttl 3600 -DnsRecords (New-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig -Cname $Auto) -Overwrite
    ```